# Trees in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1

Does someone know a stable tree adminstration plugin (nested set etc.) for the symfony framework, which is able to operate on separated database tables?

Answer (score 2):

I've heard of the [RedoTheOffice Nested Admin](http://github.com/redotheoffice/rto_nested_admin), but have never used it...

Answer (score 0):

Zed's link seems broken, these are the correct ones

http://redotheoffice.com/?p=74
http://github.com/redotheoffice/rto_nested_admin